# Capturing from the screen and saving to disk multithreaded

Tags: java, multithreading, video-capture

The follwing problem should watch the screen, record an event (a measuring textbox turns green) and record all the events leading up to it, producing a "film" of the events leading up to it. Unfortunately the whole screen needs to be recorded. I have so far done the part where the recognition takes part. However i barely get two frames per second. I would like to have around **25 to 30 fps**.

My Idea was to do the writing and reading in two seperate threads. Because the **writing event is rare and can run in the background**, the recording event can take up more time and run faster. Unfortunately the whole thing seems to be too slow. I would like to be able to write on disk the screen the 10 to 20 seconds **before** the event occurred.

Edit:
If possible i would like to stay as platform-independent as possible.

Edit 2: 
there seems to be a platform independent jar file for Xuggler. Unfortunately i don't really get how i will be able to use it for my purpose: recording the 20 seconds leading up to the point where isarecord is triggered.

Here is what i have done so far:

```
package fragrecord;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //The numbers are just silly tune parameters. Refer to the API.
        //The important thing is, we are passing a bounded queue.
        ExecutorService consumer = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,4,30,TimeUnit.SECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100));
        System.out.println("starting");
        //No need to bound the queue for this executor.
        //Use utility method instead of the complicated Constructor.
        ExecutorService producer = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        Runnable produce = new Produce(consumer);
        producer.submit(produce);  
        try {
            producer.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        consumer.shutdown();
        try {
            consumer.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

class Produce implements Runnable {
    private final ExecutorService consumer;

    public Produce(ExecutorService consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }
    boolean isarecord(BufferedImage image){
        int x=10, y = 10;
        Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(x,y));
        int red = c.getRed();
        int green = c.getGreen();
        int blue = c.getBlue();
        // Determine whether to start recording
        return false;

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        Robot robot = null;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //
        // Capture screen from the top left to bottom right
        //
        int i = 0;
        while(true) {

            i++;
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(
                new Rectangle(new Dimension(1024, 798)));

        Runnable consume = new Consume(bufferedImage,i);
        consumer.submit(consume);
        }

    }
}

class Consume implements Runnable {
    private final BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    private final Integer picnr;
    public Consume(BufferedImage bufferedImage, Integer picnr){
        this.bufferedImage = bufferedImage;
        this.picnr = picnr;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        File imageFile = new File("screenshot"+picnr+".png");
        try {
            System.out.println("screenshot"+picnr+".png");
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", imageFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a variety of reasons using executors, rewriting to nio and similar things are not going to help.

here are a bunch of things you should consider:

1. image capture is SLOW in java, nothing you can do about it without JNI dependencies
2. use jpeg instead of png, much faster
3. any image compression is SLOW using ImageIO. you could use the old-school, proprietary JpegEncoder classes (in the com.sun package) or the TurboJPEG java library (JNI as well) but imho it's not the bottleneck
4. disk i/o is DEFINITELY not the problem (you're writing <5mb/s, so don't worry)
5. writing many images in parallel will in fact slow down your application, not speed it up (unless you have an ssd)
6. consider parallelizing the capture/analysis thread instead (e.g. do the analysis only every 20th frame) (*)
7. i bet you would finish writing this app twice for each platform using a native language before you can optimize the java app enough so it runs at 25fps (using 100% cpu xD)
8. seriously consider hybrid solutions as well; e.g. record *everything* to a compressed movie with an available tool, then do the analysis later (**)

in one word: java sucks at what you want to do, really badly.

nevertheless, i've written my own version of this tool. 
http://pastebin.com/5h285fQw

one thing it does is allow to record a smaller rectangle following the mouse. 
at 500x500 it gets me easily to 25fps with images being written in the background (image compress+write takes 5-10ms for me, so it writes much faster than it records)

---

(*) you don't talk about how you analyze the images, but this seems to be the primary source  of your performance problem. a few ideas:

- only look at every N-th frame
- take a capture of only a subportion of the screen and move that subportion around over time (later reasemble the images; this will cause terrible tearing but maybe it doesn't matter for your purpose)
- capturing itself should be "not too slow" (maybe 10-20fps for fullscreen); use serial capture but parallelize the analysis

(**) on macosx you can use the built-in quicktime x to record to hdd quite efficiently; on windows i heard playclaw (http://www.playclaw.com/) is quite good and maybe worth the money (think what you'd make in the time wasted optimizing the java beast :) )

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to edit your code a little, Instead of creating `png` files I have tried creating `bmp` files which removes overhead time of  data compression, but at the cost of disk space.

Result : I do not know how to count fps but the solution is faster that yours. :-)

Comment: thanks, i did not expect this. i will incorporate into my code.

Answer (score 3):

You should measure how much time `robot.createScreenCapture()` takes. Chances are that it needs more than 40 ms which means there is no way to achieve what you want with pure Java. In my experience, the call can be very slow.

I did manage to get that time down considerably with a trick but it works only on Unix: Start a VNC server (= desktop in RAM). I patched the source code for [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) to use NIO to write the images to disk using a memory mapped file. That gave me about 10-20 fps.

Here is the code to write an image using NIO:

```
private File pixelFile = new File("tmp", "pixels.nio").getAbsoluteFile();
private IntBuffer intBuffer;
private FileChannel rwChannel;

private MappedByteBuffer byteBuffer;
private int[] pixels;

private void createMemoryMappedFile() {
    File dir = pixelFile.getParentFile();
    if(!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        rwChannel = new RandomAccessFile(pixelFile, "rw").getChannel();

        int width = ...;
        int height = ...;
        pixels = new int[width*height];

        byteBuffer = rwChannel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, width * height * 4);
        intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating NIO file " + pixelFile, e);
    }
}

public void saveImage() {

     buffer.position(0);
     buffer.put(image.getRaster().getPixels(0,0,width,height,pixels));

     flushPixels();
}

private void flushPixels() {
    byteBuffer.force();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the whole thing has to work on mac and windows. thanks though :-)

Comment: There are VNC servers for Mac and Windows, too. I just never used them, so I have no idea what they can do. On Unix, you get a whole desktop in RAM; you don't have to share the actual desktop, so you can run the server and still use the mouse+keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

Your biggest problem is that you only get one thread to actually create images. The *ThreadPoolExecutor* does not create threads the way you expect it to.

From the javadoc

- If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
- If corePoolSize or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.
- If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.

So, it will use only one thread unless the queue is full. At this time you have 100 screenshots in memory which is adding work to the GC. If I set the core threads to 4 (I have 4  cores on my laptop) and increase the memory to 1 GB I manage to capture 20 FPS or so.

If your output to disk is limiting you could store the last 400 written images as byte arrays in a queue and only write them to disk when the button turned "green". However in my tests these images would take more than 100MB of ram, so again, make sure you have enough memory.

Comment: How would i modify my ThreadPoolExecutor to work correctly? I assume i have 3 cores - one for my computation and 3 for me on a quadcore machine. Memory should be around 2-3 GB. Disk space is not limited.

Comment: The pool is working "correctly", just not how most people would expect. If you set the core threads to 3, then you will always have 3 threads working or ready to work. On my machine (2.6 GHz, 4 core i7) just getting the snapshot takes about 50ms, so that would limit it to 20 fps. The other three cores seems able to keep up and so does the disk (SSD). But, the machine is working quite hard at that point.

Comment: i set the number of processes that work concurrently to 3 now. I am getting better results for that. I will work in a means to measure fps now and update this. Maybe i will set a bounty, since some people have interest in this.

Answer (score 1):

Off topic, but look at [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler). It would be useful, if you want to create video with Java.

Edit: Also, you may optimize your image-consumer code if you don't dump each picture to disk, but append them to byte array, and dump it rarely on disk.

Edit 2: there is **"no-install" version of library** and maven dependency for it (jar with pre-compiled platform-specific libraries): [blog.xuggle.com/2012/04/03/death-to-installers](http://blog.xuggle.com/2012/04/03/death-to-installers) and [xuggle.com/xuggler/downloads](http://xuggle.com/xuggler/downloads)

Comment: if possible i want to stay away from native code as much as possible. edited my question as such.

Comment: but if i find a method to effectively deploy juggler on macs, too, i maybe will use it. i don't really want to hassle the user with installing stuff from the internet.

Comment: @tarrasch, I understand you. But, as I know, there is much overhead, when you're trying to access to external resources from inside of jvm (especially for large amounts of data, such as full bitmap of screen).

Comment: @tarrasch, Also, you may optimize your image-consumer code if you don't dump each picture to disk, but append them to byte array, and dump whole array much rarely on disk.

Comment: is there a way i can bundle xuggler in my jar? i will set a bounty for this i think. An easily deployable solution with xuggler would be fine i think.

Comment: @tarrasch, Look at this: http://blog.xuggle.com/2012/04/03/death-to-installers/ Also, look here: http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/downloads there is "no-install" version and maven dependency for it

Comment: thats actually pretty awesome. can you include the xuggler code into my application recording the 20 seconds up to isarecord is triggered? i will then award a bounty of 50 instantly.

Comment: @tarrasch, Look at this example: https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/CaptureScreenToFile.java it looks very similar to your case